# what is the formula of counting number of unique strings in one column in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm on a crystal report and want to show the how many unique receiver IDs (not repeatable) in a column. what is the formula can execute the goal above? thanks.

a few crystal report classes but no coding background.

I tried to put "select count ((distinct{RECEIVER.ID})" but it says the ) is missing.

Comment: It's right, you used (( but only )

Comment: select count ((distinct{RECEIVER.ID}))

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a missing ) in your formula:

```
select count ((distinct{RECEIVER.ID}))
```

I usually use the `DisctinctCount` Formula

```
 DistinctCount({RECEIVER.ID})
```